# How to find ratio of multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have columns like

```
total_balance, b1_amt, b2_amt, b3_amt, b4_amt, b5_amt
```

and there are more than 100 columns in all - how can I find ratio of each column in new columns?

For example I tried

```
df['ratio_b1]=df[b1_amt]/total_balance
```

but if I apply this approach then I should write code for each columns since there are more than 100 columns so how can I possible to write it all in single code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow..Please share the sample data for the ppl who would be working on the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your columns are *all* named consistently using the exact pattern in your question, you can do something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    df['ratio_b{}'.format(i)] = df['b{}_amt'.format(i)] / df['total_balance']
```

Comment: it worked thank you but how can i use it if  columns like this 2017-6-20,2017-7-10,2017-8-17,2018-2-22 and more columns

Comment: Are they part of a `DatetimeIndex` in the columns, or are they strings? Probably best to ask a new question to provide more details, and for better exposure.

Comment: columns are strings any solution for this problem?

Comment: Something like `for col in df.filter(regex='\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}'): df['ratio_' + col] = df[col] / df['total_balance']`